# метка на карте yandex.map после поиска

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Есть яндекс карта. в ней поиск по объектам. Нужно что бы человек к примеру ввел какой то адрес, нажал найти, и после этого надо поставить отметку на карте этого объекта.
Есть какое то событие поиска по карте, что бы я мог его отловить, узнать координаты объекта и поставить метку?

Answer (score 1):

[control.SearchControl](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/control.SearchControl-docpage/) позволяет обрабатывать поисковые запросы. Для примера получим координаты искомого места:

```js
function init() {
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [55.74, 37.58],
    zoom: 13,
    controls: []
  });

  // Создадим элемент управления поиск
  var searchControl = new ymaps.control.SearchControl({
    options: {
      provider: 'yandex#search'
    }
  });

  // Добавим поиск на карту
  myMap.controls.add(searchControl);

  // Нужное нам событие (выбор результата поиска)
  searchControl.events.add('resultselect', function(e) {
    var index = e.get('index');
    searchControl.getResult(index).then(function(res) {

      console.info(res.geometry.getCoordinates()); // получаем координаты найденной точки

      /* Можем ставить метку */


    });
  })
}

ymaps.ready(init);
```

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```